# PHP redirect without saving in history

Tags: php, redirect, browser

Good afternoon! The question arose. I'm using PHP. User goes to example.com/in/ and the script redirects to http://example.com/ (using header("Location: ...") ;). How to avoid saving example.com/in/ in the browser history?

Comment: This sounds like the XY problem. What do you gain by not saving this in history? Why the requirement to implement in PHP?

Answer (score 3):

I was fighting the same problem as you and this is what I found:

**PHP:**

There is no such function in php, there is a way to replace a previous similar header in php though, but I don't think that this is what you are looking for! ([php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php))

**Javascript:**

There are several functions and ways to directly or indirectly manipulate the browser history:

- You can use `window.location.replace("http://...")` to redirect a user without saving the current page to the browser history
- `window.history.back()` to redirect the user one page back in the browser history (acts exactly like the back button of the browser)
- `window.history.forward()` same as window.history.back() but forward
- `window.history.go(index)` loads a specific page from session history, using its relative position in session history as an index (the current page has the index 0)
- for more information about manipulating the browser history with `history.replaceState()`and `history.pushState()` read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

**To answer your question:**

Depending on what you are doing you can use one of these js-methods. Unfortunately, as mentioned, there is no such thing in PHP if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

although this page pops up quite high in google results, this question has been answered elsewhere with the suggestion to send before anything else a 301 header and then sending the location header.

> Send a 301 Header. header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');

IIRC Mozilla specifications back in the 2000s mentionned not storing 301 in history, and nowadays I believe Chrome doesn't store in history location changes that were not related to user interaction.

That being said the javascript option might be more adapted to your needs (you person reading this, as the OP has probably sorted their problem long ago).

edit : also forgot to mention this is  an implementation of the POST/REDIRECT/GET pattern which you can read about on wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get